# Canonical Location Parameter

Tags: generalized-linear-model, terminology, link-function

What does "Canonical Location Parameter" mean?  I'm looking for a general meaning of this term and then separately within the context of generalized linear models.z

**UPDATE**
Given how often this term comes up in my readings, I'm surprised no one has an answer yet?

Can anyone provide any help with this?

Comment: It's a relatively infrequent term, but Googling answers your question: https://www.google.com/search?q="Canonical+Location+Parameter"

Answer (score 0):

Olsson 2002 cites Lindsey 1997:

> The canonical link is that function which
> transforms the mean to a canonical location parameter of the exponential
> dispersion family member (Lindsey, 1997)

Reading from Lindsey 1997, they say the following:

> In the simplest case, the canonical
> location parameter is equated to a linear function of other parameters, of
> the form $$\theta_i (\mu_i) = \sum_j x_{ij}\beta_j$$ where $\mathbf{\beta}$ is a vector of $p < n$ (usually) unknown parameters, the matrix $\mathbf{X}_{n \times p} = [\mathbf{x}_1^T, \cdots, \mathbf{x}_n^T]^T$ is a set of known explanatory variables, the conditions, called the *design* or *model matrix*, and $\mathbf{X \beta}$ is the *linear structure*.

> Then, the canonical link function is that function which transforms the mean to a canonical location parameter of the exponential dispersion family member.